# proper IF statement issue causing parse error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am searching for a formula to combine three things. To capture the value of Cell A into cell B. If it has has a number then it should capture that number. If the value of cell A1 is - then it should change to blank in cell B1 and if it has a blank cell in A1 Then it should be blank in B1.

I have tried the formula in google sheet with IF, And OR combining but it is giving an error.

```
=if(OR(A1="-"," "),(A1=" ", " "))
```

---

```
=if(And(A1="-"," "),(A1=" ", " "))
```

---

```
=IF(A1="-"," ",IF(A1="","",IF(A1=" "," ")))
```

The expected results are giving an error or it gives the answer as false.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at IF [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) to understand it better, but the main thing here is to remember that IF is  `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

The best option here would be to go with player0 solution, because it covers up almost every case: `=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), A1, )`

But just to help you out on understanding what was wrong with your formulas, even though those solutions don't check if A1 is a number:

> =if(OR(A1="-"," "),(A1=" ", " "))

The correct way would be: `=if( OR(A1="-",A1=" "), " ", A1)`

---

> =if(And(A1="-"," "),(A1=" ", " "))

This one is actually conceptually wrong, because you want to check if A1 = "-" AND A1 =" ", which is impossible and will never be true, because a cell can't be equal to "-" and " " at the same time.

---

> =IF(A1="-"," ",IF(A1="","",IF(A1=" "," ")))

The correct way would be: =IF(A1="-"," ",IF(A1="","",IF(A1=" "," ",**A1**)))

Comment: `"because a cell can't be equal to "-" and " " at the same time"` - unless we enable quantum mode in google sheets :)

Answer (score 0):

that is not how you should use `IF` function.

> If the value of cell A1 is - then it should change to blank in cell B1 and if it has blank cell in A1 Then it should be blank in B1

which could be solved like this in B1 cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), A1, )
```

---

and arrayformula of that would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A*1), A1:A, ))
```

[image]